# EXPO - WebView is not rendering correctly after upgrading to sdk 33 (fusioncharts html)

Tags: react-native, webview, sdk, expo, fusioncharts

SDK Version: 33

Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android

My app displays charts using fusioncharts library. It was all working fine on sdk 32, the chart is loaded using a html file as base and is displayed on a webview.

[Asset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqp3Z.png)

[image]

[Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1qTn.png)

[image]

SDK 32 (WORKING)

[Sdk 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTc2P.jpg)
[image]

After upgrading to SDK 33 (Not Working, shows html content)

[Sdk 33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDbQ2.jpg)
[image]

Does anybody know what happened? Expo asset changed? Webview?

Regards,

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?    If you fixed or not,, let me know .    I want to discuss with you.              I am also having this same issue.    Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value passed to the `source` method of WebView to `{html: this.props.libraryPath}`

Conclusion, it should look like this:

```sh
<WebView
    // ... other methods

    source={{ html: this.props.libraryPath }}

    // ... other methods
/>
```

Hope this Helps!